# laravel display of image

Tags: image, laravel, directory, photo

I have a problem with the display of the image, for example : 
the image in the **Albums** folder displays very well, BUT if I put the image in the **Pictures** folder it is not displayed!

```
src = "{{URL::asset("img/users/{$user->id}/pictures/{$serve->image}")}}"
```

Comment: What would happen if you try to open an image from `pictures` folder in the new tab? Just an image itself. Also please provide server and/or laravel logs.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing it with url ,you have to concatenate it like this
src = "{{URL::asset("img/users/{$user->id}/pictures/."'$serve->image'".")}}"

Comment: Always the image is not displayed!
As I said previously the image is displayed when I put it in the folder albumes, but it is not displayed when I put it in the folder pictures!?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
src = "/img/users/{{$user->id}}/pictures/{{$serve->image}}"
```

Comment: Always the image is not displayed!!! BUT is displayed when I put it in the folder albumes!?

Comment: Komal, how your answer will help nabil?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using is correct but I think the path with **"pictures/"** directory is incorrect. So always put a check of file_exist before displaying it like:

```
if (file_exists(public_path('/img/users/'.$serve->image))) {    
    // show image
}
```

Comment: How do I make the verification of the existence of folder in the view!?

Comment: The folder exists after the verification of the dossier, but always the image is not displayed!

    if(file_exists( storage_path().'/img/users/'.$user->id.'/pictures/'.$serve->image ))
        <img class = "media-object" style="width: 250px; height: auto;" src="../img/users/{{$user->id}}/pictures/{{$serve->image}}" alt="">
      else
        <img class = "media-object" style="width: 250px; height: auto;" src="/images/photos/account/default.png" alt="">
      endif